# React- this.props.history.push('pathname') does not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently writing a small CRUD application. For my frontend I am using React v6. In my code I have a list of the Entity and above that I would have a button that takes me to a form that lets me add a new entry in the table. However, Even though I have routed the different URLs, after clicking the button I just get an error saying: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

The lines of code in question are:

```
addContractor() {
        this.props.history.push("/add-contractor");
    }
```

In my App.js file I have the appropriate routing as well:

```
<Route path="/add-contractor" element = {<CreateContractorComponent/>}/>
```

I am not sure why this is happening and I would like some insight and explanation as I am very new to frontend development.

Thanks.

Comment: in `react-router-dom v@6` there is `useHistory()` hook, did you look into it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with nested components, try nesting the `Switch` without wrapping it with a `BrowserRouter` in `App.js` file.

If it doesn't work try this alternative too, Might be a few things that have changed in the documentation. Import `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory` and for reference go through this blog - https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/